# QMap не возвращает тип значение в методе value(key)

Tags: c++, qt

QMap у которого ключ строка, а значение соккет , при попытки вызвать значение по ключу выдает непонятно что, только не соккет.
Пример:

```
QMap<QString,QTcpSocket> map;
map.insert("qwe",socket);
map.value("qwe").write("test"); // error
```

Comment: Что за ошибка выводится?

Comment: no matching function "write"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QMap::value возвращает const значение https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html#value
QTcpSocket::write неконстантный метод, отсюда и ошибка, т.к. константной функции write нет

```
map["qwe"].write("test"); // ok
```

Comment: То есть из константного значения нельзя вызвать не константное свойство?

Comment: @Amos, ну, это ж с++ у нас у тут, так что способы есть, но в общем случае, если у вас надо вызывать неконстантные методы у константных объектов, то стоит пересмотреть архитектуру.